# Pop_os Slow Boot time

Tags: boot, swap, pop-os

I am experiencing slow boot times.
Can anybody help?
Thank you all

Processor: Intel i5-2450M
Memory (RAM): 16GB
Graphics: AMD
Laptop Model: Toshiba Satellite L850-142
PopOS ver: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS

systemd-analyze

```
Startup finished in 10.862s (kernel) + 1min 39.205s (userspace) = 1min 50.068s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 39.158s in userspace
```

systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 39.158s
└─multi-user.target @1min 39.157s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @1min 31.029s +8.127s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 30.967s +53ms
      └─network.target @1min 30.825s
        └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 30.720s +78ms
          └─basic.target @1min 30.569s
            └─dbus-broker.service @1min 30.524s +42ms
              └─dbus.socket @1min 30.495s
                └─sysinit.target @1min 30.485s
                  └─snapd.apparmor.service @1.901s +270ms
                    └─apparmor.service @1.661s +204ms
                      └─local-fs.target @1.659s
                        └─boot.mount @1.621s +37ms
                          └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d6e59357\x2de963\x>
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d6e59357\x2de963\x2d46dc\x2d9>
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

systemd-analyze blame

```
8.127s plymouth-quit-wait.service
6.898s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
2.760s apt-daily-upgrade.service
1.943s snapd.service
1.640s accounts-daemon.service
1.312s dev-loop6.device
1.296s dev-loop2.device
1.295s dev-loop4.device
1.294s dev-loop5.device
1.285s dev-loop7.device
1.241s dev-loop1.device
1.239s dev-loop3.device
1.216s dev-loop0.device
1.208s fwupd.service
1.002s dev-sda3.device
 973ms com.system76.Scheduler.service
 901ms snapd.seeded.service
 675ms networkd-dispatcher.service
 653ms gpu-manager.service
 645ms apt-daily.service
 639ms ufw.service
 621ms udisks2.service
 616ms man-db.service
 568ms e2scrub_reap.service
 508ms upower.service
 489ms chrony.service
 473ms systemd-logind.service
 389ms apport.service
 370ms pop-default-settings-zram.service
 360ms smartmontools.service
 360ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
 339ms user@111.service
 331ms vboxdrv.service
 322ms switcheroo-control.service
 270ms snapd.apparmor.service
 270ms dev-loop8.device
 263ms user@1000.service
 263ms logrotate.service
 262ms ModemManager.service
 246ms systemd-resolved.service
 212ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 204ms apparmor.service
 202ms gdm.service
 184ms NetworkManager.service
 184ms systemd-rfkill.service
 179ms avahi-daemon.service
 175ms com.system76.PowerDaemon.service
 155ms pulseaudio-enable-autospawn.service
 148ms systemd-journal-flush.service
 146ms polkit.service
 141ms systemd-journald.service
 129ms keyboard-setup.service
 125ms lm-sensors.service
 122ms systemd-binfmt.service
 111ms openvpn.service
 107ms systemd-udevd.service
 100ms bluetooth.service
  91ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
  85ms rsyslog.service
  84ms systemd-modules-load.service
  80ms lvm2-monitor.service
  78ms wpa_supplicant.service
  77ms thermald.service
  76ms packagekit.service
  70ms dpkg-db-backup.service
  69ms networking.service
  62ms systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl0.service
  59ms fwupd-refresh.service
  59ms systemd-sysctl.service
  55ms systemd-random-seed.service
  53ms systemd-user-sessions.service
  52ms dev-hugepages.mount
  51ms dev-mqueue.mount
  50ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d6e59357\x2de963\x2d46dc\x2d90cb\x2d84c>
  49ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  49ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  48ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
  43ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
  42ms dbus-broker.service
  42ms kmod-static-nodes.service
  41ms snap-bare-5.mount
  41ms modprobe@configfs.service
  40ms modprobe@drm.service
  39ms com.system76.SystemUpdater.service
  39ms snap-bing\x2dwall-26.mount
  38ms modprobe@fuse.service
  37ms snap-core22-858.mount
  37ms boot.mount
  36ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
  35ms snap-core22-864.mount
  34ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
  32ms alsa-restore.service
  32ms plymouth-start.service
  32ms snap-qt5\x2dcore22-10.mount
  29ms snap-qt5\x2dcore22-12.mount
  27ms snapd.socket
  27ms snap-snapd-20092.mount
  26ms colord.service
  25ms snap-snapd-20290.mount
  24ms console-setup.service
  23ms cups.service
  23ms systemd-sysusers.service
  23ms finalrd.service
  22ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  21ms grub-common.service
  20ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  18ms plymouth-read-write.service
  18ms dev-sda2.swap
  17ms user-runtime-dir@111.service
  16ms rtkit-daemon.service
  15ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
  12ms systemd-update-utmp.service
  11ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
  10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   8ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   8ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   7ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
   6ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
   5ms modprobe@ramoops.service
   5ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
   4ms ifupdown-pre.service
   4ms vboxautostart-service.service
   4ms vboxweb-service.service
   4ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
   3ms setvtrgb.service
   1ms motd-news.service
  63us blk-availability.service
lines 105-127/127 (END)
```

boot.log

1 of 2) A start job is running for /…apper/cryptswap (1min 26s / no li[  * ] (1 of 2) A start job is running for /…apper/cryptswap (1min 27s / no li[   *] (2 of 2) A start job is running for /…88-b64ec0a9abe6 (1min 29s / 1min [    **] (2 of 2) A start job is running for /…88-b64ec0a9abe6 (1min 29s / 1min [ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device f1-ba13-4f1c-ba88-b64ec0a9abe6.

```
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for cryptswap.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/cryptswap.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/cryptswap.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swaps.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local Encrypted Volumes.
```

cat /etc/fstab

```
/etc/fstab: static file system information.

Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

<file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=d6e59357-e963-46dc-90cb-84c169d510f5  /boot  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap  none  swap  defaults  0  0
UUID=0c628e55-8d8c-4d7d-96ed-9721fcaa11c2  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
UUID=d6e59357-e963-46dc-90cb-84c169d510f5  /boot       ext4    defaults      0       2
/dev/sda2 none swap sw 0 0
```

blkid

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="23eb8895-d9e4-4388-9555-91b29b792ab6" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="54295aed-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="0c628e55-8d8c-4d7d-96ed-9721fcaa11c2" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="54295aed-03"
```